# How does redirection work between arguments

Tags: bash, scripting, io-redirection

Given a command like this:

```
command <inputfile> <outputfile>
```

And then called like this:

```
command FileA > FileC FileB
```

It takes `A` and `B` as input and outputs to `C`, but how can it parse the third argument, since the output redirection is between the arguments?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The shell parses the command-line, and sets up redirection. In this case, it sees `> FileC`, sets up the corresponding redirection, and removes those terms from the command: so what ends up being executed is

```
command FileA FileB
```

`command` itself never sees the `> FileC` part.

See [What are the shell's control and redirection operators?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/159513/86440) for details on redirection in general.